# Wrong commit during release:prepare and release:branch

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I use **maven release plugin 2.3.2** and **maven 3.0.4** and I have a problem during prepare and branch phase.

I have an **svn** path like `http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1`. The **App1** contains 3 directories:

```
App1/trunk
App1/branches
App1/tags
```

trunk contains

```
App1/trunk/ApplicationParent
App1/trunk/ApplicationChild
```

so, I would like to create a new tag with only `ApplicationParent` and `ApplicationChild`. So, I have created configuration in my `pom.xml` where I put something like this:

```
<scm>   
<connection>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk</connection> 
<developerConnection>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk</developerConnection>
<url>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk</url>
</scm> 


<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<tagBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/tags</tagBase>
<branchBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/branches</branchBase>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

next, I performed `mvn release:prepare` and maven created new tag `ApplicationParent-1.0` where all from `App1 (trunk, branches and tags)` are included, I don't know why because in `scm` I set only

`http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk` so I expected to tag all from trunk dictionary, but maven created `ApplicationParent-1.0` and put `trunk, branches and tags` directories. Why ?

So, I changed my scm to `http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk/ApplicationParent` and performed `mvn release:prepare` again, now it is fine, in ApplicationParent-1.1 I have all from trunk directory.

But, If I perform `mvn release:branch` using `http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk/ApplicationParent` , I can have new branch only with `ApplicationParent`, but I need to create 
a branch for all trunk dictionaries, so I need to change `scm` to `http://svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk/` and it is good if I want to create branch. But if I need to create new tag using `release:perform` I have the problem that I have described above.

Why can't I use path like `http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/trunk` for both `release:perform` and `release:branch` ?

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling that your SCM is not structured in a way that the Maven Release Plugin is happy with.  The [following article explains some of the structures that the plugin understands](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-miles/maven-release-flat-project-structures-revisited).

While the format you describe is supported, you're not reflecting that in the pom.xml file and/or you're trying to use a single pom.xml file for what is essentially two different projects (ApplicationParent vs ApplicationChild).

I would suggest restructuring your SCM to be:

```
App1/ApplicationParent
    /trunk
    /tags
    /branches
    /releases
App1/ApplicationChild
    /trunk
    /tags
    /branches
    /releases
```

Then your developer connection in the pom.xml for ApplicationParent can be:

```
<developerConnection>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationParent/trunk</developerConnection>
```

and the tag/branch base:

```
<tagBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationParent/tags</tagBase>
<branchBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationParent/branches</branchBase>
```

And for the child project:

```
<developerConnection>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationChild/trunk</developerConnection>
```

and the tag/branch base:

```
<tagBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationChild/tags</tagBase>
<branchBase>http:/svn.pyhost.com/projects/App1/ApplicationChild/branches</branchBase>
```

My personal taste however, is to only do the release plugin from a release branch (such as /releases/x.y.z) instead of the /trunk.  So you branch inside the SCM, then checkout the new release branch and do the release:prepare and release:perform magic on the release branch.

Don't forget to use: "mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true" so that you can see what it is going to do before the actual release.  Once that works fine, you can do a "release:clean release:prepare release:perform" as a single maven command.